# Как вывести имя файла который сейчас проигрывается?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть проигрыватель медиа файлов который использует библиотеку VLCJ.
Как мне вывести на консоль имя файла что сейчас проигрывается?
Вот код программы:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;

import java.util.List;

import static uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx.videosurface.ImageViewVideoSurfaceFactory.videoSurfaceForImageView;


/**
 *
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    private final MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;
    private final MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactoryPanel;

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayer embeddedMediaPlayer;
    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayer embeddedMediaPlayerPanel;

    private ImageView videoImageView;
    private ImageView panelImageView;

    private final KeyCombination CLOSED_FULL_SCREEN =
            new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.SHIFT_DOWN); //Shift+S


    public Main() {
        this.mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        this.embeddedMediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        this.embeddedMediaPlayer.events().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void playing(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void paused(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {


            }

            @Override
            public void stopped(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void timeChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, long newTime) {
            }

        });
        this.mediaPlayerFactoryPanel = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        this.embeddedMediaPlayerPanel = mediaPlayerFactoryPanel.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.videoImageView = new ImageView();
        this.panelImageView = new ImageView();


        embeddedMediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(videoSurfaceForImageView(this.videoImageView));
        embeddedMediaPlayerPanel.videoSurface().set(videoSurfaceForImageView(this.panelImageView));
    }

    @Override
    public final void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        List<String> params = getParameters().getRaw();
        if (params.size() != 1) {
            System.out.println("Specify a single MRL");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Pane root = new Pane();

        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        //размер и размещения видео
        videoImageView.setFitHeight(800);//висота
        videoImageView.setFitWidth(1680);//ширина
        videoImageView.setLayoutX(0);
        videoImageView.setLayoutY(0);
        //размер и размещения видео панели
        panelImageView.setFitHeight(200);
        panelImageView.setFitWidth(1680);
        panelImageView.setLayoutX(0);
        panelImageView.setLayoutY(800);

        root.getChildren().add(videoImageView);
        root.getChildren().add(panelImageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1920, 1080);
        primaryStage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                //Handle
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);//поверх всех окон
        primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");

        // отлавливаем нажатие Shift+S для закрытия программы
        primaryStage.getScene().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if(CLOSED_FULL_SCREEN.match(event)) {
                stop();
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        primaryStage.show();

        System.out.println(embeddedMediaPlayer.media().play("media/"));
        embeddedMediaPlayerPanel.media().play("panel/");



    }

    @Override
    public final void stop() {
        embeddedMediaPlayer.controls().play();
        embeddedMediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayerFactory.release();

        embeddedMediaPlayerPanel.controls().play();
        embeddedMediaPlayerPanel.release();
        mediaPlayerFactoryPanel.release();

    }

    public void play(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```